# Umbraco 7 with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have following questions about using Umbraco 7 CMS with MVC application as I am new to Umbraco.

1) Is it possible to store & retrieve customer specific content like images etc. in Umbraco. In Umbraco database I do not see anything like Client/ Client ID that will indicate content is client specific.

2) If there is nothing client specific in Umbraco, I want to use the other option. i.e, store content in  custom database and link it with client. Is this the proper way?

3) We can create multiple sub-domains in Umbraco which look like http://example.com/Client1, http://example.com/Client2 etc. but can we create sites that look like http://Client1.example.com, http://Client2.example.com ? If yes, how to achieve that ?

4) Are the Umbraco video tutorials useful? I read that they are suitable for WebForms only.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how you will be setting up your customers? Will they be members in Umbraco? Or are you using some sort of external system to manage that? If your customer's are set up as Members in Umbraco, you can create custom member types (sort of like a document type for a member) and then add member specific data to that member type. For example, you could create a "Customer" member type that has fields for address, and a Media Picker for a thumbnail icon. You could also do as Claus has suggested below and add a picker for a media folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, but since umbraco isn't built specifically for your use-case you will most likely have to do some work yourself to achieve this. Usually developers would create a specific root folder in the media library per client and then use pickers scoped to this folder. The same thing can be done with content pickers. The actual implementation however depends a lot on what exactly it is you need to do.

2) You are free to store data in a custom database and then load it into umbraco using some kind of provider/repository or whatever you feel like. As umbraco is just a "framework" you are in no way limited as to what other code you write in other parts of your .NET solution. You are also not limited by umbraco to any specific ORM tool so feel free to use whatever you like.

3) You can just register those hostnames with subdomains in the same way as you register the subdomains you listed (right click the root node for the subdomain you want and go to hostnames). Just remember that those subdomains should also be mapped in your IIS, otherwise the requests will never actually reach umbraco.

4) Yep they are very useful - they have been updated to more recent code instead of webforms and it is a good introduction to most of the things you will need as a web developer using umbraco.